# how to get value of dropdownlist of a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In the edittemplate of a gridview i have a dropdownlist which will provide a list of values when click on the edit button of each gridview row.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack=false  OnLoad="DropDownList1_onload"
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</EditItemTemplate>
```

c#

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.Parent.Parent;
    int idx = row.RowIndex;

    DropDownList txtECustCode = (DropDownList)row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
    string _text1 = txtECustCode.selectedvalue();

}
protected void DropDownList1_onload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=CHANGEME1;Initial Catalog=Reflection;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select salary from employee", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();
        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataTextField = "salary";
        ddl.DataValueField = "salary";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));


}
```

so when i click on edit button the onload event will get fired and list down data from database. when i select an item of the dropdown, i need to access the dropdownlist selected value.

**But whenever i changed the dropdown before selectedindexchanged the onload function invoked again which inturn refresh the content and return the selectedindex as 0.**

how can i prevent this?

Comment: Nevermind, misread your code.

Comment: Is the `SelectedIndexChanged` event fired at the same time the update happens, like during a selection?

Comment: No. when i select item and click on the update button this event will fired.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your question.  Is this in the ball park:  "I need to prevent the update from occurring if the drop down has focus?"

Comment: whenever i changed the dropdown, before 'selectedindexchanged' the 'onload' function invoked again which in turn refresh the content and return the selectedindex as 0. so even if i selected 4th value, the value returned will be 0 since the onload refresh the control before the selectedindex invoked.

Comment: Based on your comments I wrote you an answer.  Let me know if this is what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments I think you need to save your current value before you refresh every time.  Lets assume that index 0 is always the "blank" value that we can ignore. Change your onload method slightly to provide the save and re-select

```
protected void DropDownList1_onload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SAVE SELECTED
    string selected = "";
    if(DropDownList1.Items.Count > 0 && DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
         selected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
     }
    //UPDATE
    SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=CHANGEME1;Initial Catalog=Reflection;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select salary from employee", cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    da.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();
    ddl.DataSource = ds;
    ddl.DataTextField = "salary";
    ddl.DataValueField = "salary";
    ddl.DataBind();
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    //RESELECT
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selected))
    {
         DropDownList1.SelectedValue = selected;
    }
}
```

Essentially, you need to save what you have selected before the update IF something is selected.  Then after the update, reselect it.  My code is just an example you may need to tweak it to actually capture and re-find the element that was actually selected before the update.

Comment: Great Logic..With a small change you make my code work. Thanks a Ton.